# Update Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Dear Stackoverflowers,

I'm writing to you since my understanding of simple programming paradigms got completely destroyed while encountering a problem which cannot be simpler.

I have a simple Angular.js `$scope` function which is called on after a [angular-sortable-view](https://github.com/kamilkp/angular-sortable-view) `sv-on-stop` event. The param `items` equals the variable `$part` which contains the new (sorted) array of objects (not neccesary for this issue):

```
$scope.update = function(items) {
    var data = [{
        'id': 'ZZZZ',
        'order': 2
    },{
        'id': 'AAAA',
        'order': 1
    },{
        'id': 'HHHH',
        'order': 0
    }];
    console.log(data);
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
        data[i].order = i;
    };
    console.log(data);
}
```

Expected output of the first `console.log` to the console:

```
data [{id:'ZZZZ',order:2},{id:'AAAA',order:1},{id:'HHHH',order:0}]
```

Real  output of the first `console.log` to the console:

```
data [{id:'ZZZZ',order:0},{id:'AAAA',order:1},{id:'HHHH',order:2}]
```

The second `console.log` returns the exactly same.
Is Angular.js using some sort of pre-caching or something, because the first `console.log` returns the sorted object-array? I would absolutely appreciate a Stackoverflow-styled short explanation on this. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`console.log()` in some browsers can have some odd timings when you pass it an object (like you are doing).  I would suggest you try this:

```
$scope.update = function(items) {
    var data = [{
        'id': 'ZZZZ',
        'order': 2
    },{
        'id': 'AAAA',
        'order': 1
    },{
        'id': 'HHHH',
        'order': 0
    }];
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
        data[i].order = i;
    };
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

to eliminate any of those timing issues.

The theory is that `console.log()` has to marshall data to another process and that takes some time and is done in the background.  When you pass it an object, it does NOT make a copy of that object (it just hangs onto a reference), but it also doesn't process the data on the object immediately.  So, if you immediately modify the object, your first `console.log()` might not show the state of the object at the right time.

I don't know what browsers are subject to this, but I do know that I've seen the issue myself in Chrome.

Comment: I agree here, stringifying will create an object which is not updatable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the good explenation. That worked very well. So my first approach with `console.log(data)` that showed the result immediately just displayed a wrong value? And this effect is caused by `console.log()` timing issues I am not responsible of? I will mark your answer as "accepted" afterwards.

Comment: @MartinWeise - yes that is a correct understanding.  It is technically a "limitation" or "bug" in the `console.log()` implementation in some browsers.  It's probably done that way for performance reasons.  Fortunately, it doesn't usually cause problems - but sooner or later you will run into it.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using the Chrome dev tools, you might be seeing the latest value, as opposed to the value at the time the console was written to.

Try this out:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
```